# Multiple OR statements inside IF statement

Tags: javascript

Slightly confused as to what is going on here:

```
var first = true;
var third = false;

if(first === true || !second || third === false) {
    alert('if');
}
else{
    alert('else');
}
```

The else statement is evaluating here each time and I'm confused as to why, first is true, there is no variable called second and third is also false, only one should have to be true to trigger the if condition, right?

Comment: where is the variable `second` assigned?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5yeo4g93/ works, which means you must be working with different code, or you've left out something crucial when pasting here.

Comment: that's correct - when I run your code I see 'if'

Comment: hmm, it could be because I'm pulling `first` and `third` from localStorage, but this hasn't presented an issue before. i.e `var first = localStorage.setItem('first', true)` then `first = localStorage.getItem('first')`

Comment: If you're pulling first and third from local storage, is it coming back as a boolean or a string value?

Comment: maybe this is what I don't know entirely, but like I said it hasn't presented an issue anywhere else I've followed the same procedure.

Comment: So find out. Log the result, and `typeof result`. If it's string, there's your problem.

Comment: far as I remember, the === operator doesn't carry out a type conversion before the comparison takes place, so if it is coming back as a string, it'll evaluate to false

Comment: ok, `typeOf` is a string. Makes sense now. Thanks

Comment: localStorage is ALWAYS returning strings... you have to convert it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting a string from `localStorage` and aren't converting it to a boolean value. Convert the string to boolean and it should work.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yeo4g93/3/)

```
var first = 'true';  //string returned from localStorage
var third = 'false';

if (Boolean(first) === true || !second || Boolean(third) === false) {
  alert('if');
}
else {
  alert('else');
}
```

Comment: Yeah I just changed it to store strings in the first place, both methods work though. Thanks.